# Vertically center CSS techniques don't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, vertical-alignment

I've gone through stackoverflow questions and a whole bunch of articles on vertically centering text like the following:
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

None of the techniques seem to work with the latest version of Chrome. Is that just the nature of Chrome? My text just always appears at the top. It seems that whenever I use 50% or 100% as values for CSS's `height` or `top`, nothing happens.

I just need a single line of text vertically centered. `line-height` isn't helpful because I want it centered in the middle of the browser window... I don't know how tall the browser window is going to be.

***UPDATE***: The problem is apparently Foundation 4. Once I delete the following everything works as expected:

```
<link href="/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Any idea on how to make it work with Foundation 4?

Answer (score 0):

I use various vertical centering methods regularly, and they still work in the latest version of chrome (31).  You've probably overlooked some small detail - can you post what you've tried?

For example:

This technique uses a `display:table-cell` wrapper with `vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;` element: http://jsbin.com/ofapiv/1/edit

And this technique uses a ghost element (a `:before` element with `height:100%` and both it and its sibling have `vertical-align:middle`): http://jsbin.com/uqutol/4/edit

And this is the ghost element technique simplified to center just a single line of text: http://jsbin.com/ubUxOgO/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Centered line</title>
<style>
  html { height:100%; }
  .singleline {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0;bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .singleline:before {
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="singleline">This is a centered line!</div>
```

Comment: The problem is apparently Foundation 4. Once I remove that stylesheet, all the normal techniques work!